# How to use GetOptions utility to handle 'optional' command-line arguments in Perl?

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments, getopt-long

There are many Perl tutorials explaining how to use GetOptions utility to process only the command-line arguments which are expected, else exit with an appropriate message.

In my requirement I have following optional command-line arguments, like,

- -z  zip_dir_path : zip the output
- -h : show help.

I tried few combinations with GetOptions which did not work for me.
So my question is: How to use GetOptions to handle this requirement?

EDIT: -z needs 'zip directory path'

EDIT2:
My script has following compulsory command-line arguments:

- -in   input_dir_path : Input directory
- -out   output_dir_path : Output directory

Here's my code:

```
my %args;
GetOptions(\%args,
"in=s",
"out=s"
) or die &usage();

die "Missing -in!" unless $args{in};
die "Missing -out!" unless $args{out};
```

Hope this EDIT adds more clarity.

Comment: Usually you call `GetOptions` and then look at what you end up with to see which switches were used. Maybe you should include a few of your attempts to clarify what's going on and what the problem is.

Comment: @mu is too short: I have updated the question text. Thank you for comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[A `:` (colon)](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Getopt-Long/lib/Getopt/Long.pm#Summary_of_Option_Specifications) can be used to indicate optional options:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;

my ( $zip, $help, $input_dir, $output_dir );

GetOptions(
    'z:s'   => \$zip,
    'h'     => \$help,
    'in=s'  => \$input_dir,
    'out=s' => \$output_dir,
);
```

Comment: I think, ':' can be used to indicate the string value for that command-line switch is optional, and not for indicating that the switch itself is optional. Am I right?

Comment: Although I have accepted `@Alan Haggai Alavi`'s answer, agree with `@mu is too short` in his comment that GetOptions is used to list the options provided by the user and the script has to process the arguments further as per need.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation:

```
   : type [ desttype ]
       Like "=", but designates the argument as optional.  If omitted, an
       empty string will be assigned to string values options, and the
       value zero to numeric options.
```

If you specify that and check for the empty string, you know which ones the user did not specify.

Answer (score 2):

This should set to `1` or `0` the values of `$zip_output` and `$show_help` based on what input arguments you get in command line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;

my $zip_output;
my $show_help;

GetOptions("z" => \$zip, "h" => \$show_help);
```

Comment: @'Tudor Constantin': I have updated my question text. Thank you for the answer.